# To extract specific pattern from file

Tags: shell, scripting

I am having below file file.txt where i need to extract pattern.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `id` string COMMENT '',
  `age` string COMMENT '',
  `city` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'path'='hdfs://local/')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://local/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',
  'EXTERNAL'='FALSE',
  'numFiles'='14',
  'numRows'='-1',
  'rawDataSize'='-1',
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='orc',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='9',
'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.8'='....":{}}]}',
  'totalSize'='12',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='12')
```

I would require below

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `id` string COMMENT '',
  `age` string COMMENT '',
  `city` string COMMENT '')
```

How is it possible to achieve in Unix ?

Comment: Unix is not a language. Tag the language you want to use

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you know number of columns in table, you can use *grep*. In this case with 3 columns use this:

```
grep -A 3 'CREATE TABLE' file.txt
```

Where 3 after -A is number of lines after match which will be included to output.

If you do not know number of columns use awk.

Comment: Actually i dont know the number of columns i wanted to have till '') closing to get the create table structure. Can you help ?

Comment: Did you google at all? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/show-all-the-file-up-to-the-match